# A curve in a submanifold with a tangent vector not necessarily in the submanifold's tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

I came across this exercise in Warner's Foundations of Differential Manifolds and Lie Groups,

Let $N \subset M$ be a submanifold. Let $\gamma \colon (a,b) \to M$ be a $C^{\infty}$ curve such that $\gamma(a,b) \subset N$. Show that it is not necessarily true that $\dot \gamma (t) \in T_{\gamma(t)}N$  for each $t \in (a,b)$.

I'm having trouble trying to find an example of such a curve. Could someone give me an example or show me the way?
Either way thanks!

Comment: Try with a figure eight in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Not every author would call that a "submanifold", though.

Comment: @Michael, this is exercise 16 on page 51. $M_m$ is the tangent space at $m \in M,$ defined as linear operators on germs of functions, page 12 Def. 1.14. On page 17, 1.23 (e) he defines $\dot{\gamma}.$ In the figures on page 23 he distinguishes three similar immersions, the one in the middle, a submanifold but not an imbedding. Warner would not call an immersed figure 8 a submanifold. On page 25, and again on page 29, he shows a noncompact submanifold figure 8, say $\gamma : (-\infty, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R^2,$ with $\gamma(0) = (0,0)$ and

Comment: then $\lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} \gamma(t) = (0,0)$ as well as  $\lim_{t \rightarrow -\infty} \gamma(t) = (0,0),$ but in both cases nearly tangent to the $y$-axis. I am not so sure that the figure 8 is an answer to this problem. Certainly he does want you to plow through the definitions and examples and learn more.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro I don´t really get why the eight figure should work, could you help me out?

Comment: My best guess right now is that this has to do with Remark 1.52 on pages 39-40, partly by comparing the Exercises on pages 50-52 with the pages of the topics involved; they are, more or less, in order.

Comment: @WillJagy thank you, i was also thinking about something like that but couldn't find anything... anyways I think i give up for now, if anybody comes up with something please let me now.

Comment: It is exactly as Giuseppe said. Suppose  $\psi:M\to \mathbb R^2$ is an injective immersion with image a figure eight with singularity at the origin and two branches along the axes.  Then $\psi(t)$ will run, say, tangent to the $x$- axis at time zero. Now there exists a curve $\gamma$ tangent to the $y$-axis, entirely contained in the figure eight, but whose velocity $\gamma'(0)\neq 0$ at time zero is along the $y$-axis.Then that velocity is not in $N_{\gamma(0)}=N_{(0,0)}=x$-axis. (To tell the truth, I don't like this definition of submanifold at all!)

Comment: all right, thanks @GeorgesElencwajg! I can see the trick now, it wasn´t hard after all... I feel a little ashamed now, but relief. Thanks so much guys!